# How can i play Two different Sounds in two Buses in AUGraph

Tags: objective-c, api, core-audio, audio-streaming, sound-synthesis

Hey Folks  Can any1 help me out,How can i play Two Different Sounds in two Different 
Buses separately in AUGraph.(i.e like One bus is having one sound and another bus having other sound ,i need to play those two sounds separately), 
Any Help can be greatly Appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample application provided by apple called MixerHost that shows you how do to this.

here is the link:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanx for your Reply,Already i worked on that Sample code,There it is having Two buses and Two sounds ,But the Sound is playing Together With out any gap,Wat i need is to make Two Sounds Separately,I tried Like hell ,but Both sounds are Playing Continuously,..

Comment: i never tried it but what if you set up two separate AuGraphs